# How to manage multiple AWS Serverless APIs with a single domain?

Tags: subdomain, serverless

I created multiple APIs using AWS Serverless Application Model ([SAM](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/sam/)) and every API created an unique URL with different domain. I would like to manage all APIs under my domain (e.g. https://api.xxx.yyy/function).

Currently I have multiple functions created and I would like to know should I config the subdomain, such that

1. https://api.xxx.yyy/function1 would be redirected to https://${ServerlessRestApi1}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod, and
2. https://api.xxx.yyy/function2 would be redirected to https://${ServerlessRestApi2}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should be able to determine this in the yaml configs, under "Domain" (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-httpapi-httpapidomainconfiguration.html#sam-property-httpapi-httpapidomainconfiguration--examples). Otherwise, anything with routing I usually opt to using Route53 to redirect everything from your custom domain.
--
ps. i think it would be useful to see what you have already done to better help you

Comment: Thanks for the info and I would take a look at the document. The domain is currently managed by GoDaddy so I am not sure if this domain setting would work in the first place.

Comment: It should still work, you just need to add your custom domain to S3. There are docs especially for GoDaddy: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/to-add-a-custom-domain-managed-by-godaddy.html

Answer (score 0):

I would aim for this type of setup, where each microservice is a set of functions:

- https://api.mycompany.com/orders/fn1
- https://api.mycompany.com/orders/fn2
- https://api.mycompany.com/customers/fn1

Each API can have its own base path in its serverless.yml file, as in [this API of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.serverless/blob/master/serverless.yml#L32), which points to endoints under https://api.authsamples.com/api.

There will then be only one API domain, that maps to the custom domain. My [write up](https://authguidance.com/serverless-api-deployment/) explains how I put this together, in case useful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am sorry that I currently is busy working on other stuff so I will validate this approach later. Thanks again for answering.